# How to continue mutiple iteratations with different ranges from a text file in bash

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, scripting, tmux

I have a text file of an arbitrary number of hostnames. Note each hostname is not numbered as below. this is just a sanitized version each hostname is unique.

```
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3
hostname4
hostname5
...
```

My use case requires me to iterate through the text file of hostnames and log into these boxes. There is currently an ssh connection limit of 6 for the jump box. I am trying to work around this. I am limited here so bear with me.

my goal at the moment is to:

1. ssh up to the first 6 hosts (the hostname list can be less than or greater than 6 hosts)
2. then run 'ls -l' on each host
3. Close the connections
4. repeat until end of the file.

i am using tmux to achieve this and split the panes for me for each host.

```
COUNTER="$(< "$1" wc -l)"                                         #This counts the number of hostnames in the file. I wrote this because i believe i need a counter somewhere to keep track of what iteration im in.


    while IFS= read -r ip || [[ -n "$ip" ]]; do                   #Read the hostname file
        tmux select-layout tiled;                                 #split the panes evenly ~roughly
        echo "$ip" | xclip -i -sel clipboard                      #copy the hostnames from the file to system clipboard
        tmux split-window -v; 
        tmux send-keys "ssh myjumpbox" ;                          #this is specific to my ssh config
        tmux send-keys "KPEnter" \ "$(xclip -o -sel clipboard)" ; #Press enter and paste IP to jumpbox
        tmux send-keys "KPEnter" ; 
        tmux send-keys "sudo su -" ;                              #become root on target host
        tmux send-keys "KPEnter" ; 
        tmux send-keys "$2" ;                                     #run [COMMAND]
        tmux send-keys "KPEnter";                                 #Press enter again
    done < "$1"
    sleep 60                                                      #Wait 60s until all the commands have fully executed
    tmux kill-pane -a -t 0                                             #Close all current ssh connections/panes besides pane 0 in order to establish new connetions for the rest of the host file
}
```

At the moment the above code can split the panes based on the number of hostnames in the file in an existing tmux shell. the issue is that once it reaches the limit of 6 connections. It will open the rest of the panes but error out with "Session open refused by peer" due to the server ssh limit.

```
#usage
./script [FILE] [COMMAND]
./script hostFile "ls -l"
```

What i am struggling with is, continuing with the hostname iteration until the file is done. In hopefully clearer terms

What i believe are my edge cases (hypothetical)

```
if the hostname file is less than 6 hosts, proceed as normal
if the hostname file is lets say 7. run the first 6, close the connection. iterate to the 7th hostname.
if the hostname file is 18, run the above code for the first 6 hosts, close, run the next 6. close. run the final 6. close.
```

I understand that what im doing is very hacky. However, I am working with minimal access. If someone can point me in the right direction code-wise in terms of how can I can achieve this iteration logic that would be much appreciated. I believe i need a `continue` statement somewhere just not sure or adjust my while-conditional. The problem is not tmux-related. As i already got that down. I just thought i post it for reference purposes. it's more an iteration-related question.

Comment: keep track of the number of jobs you've spawned in the background, once your loop counter hits 6 do a `wait -n` (wait for the first backgrounded job to complete), then (optionally) check how many jobs are still 'running' in the background, decrement your loop counter accordingly, then loop again until you hit 6 again, then `wait -n` again, repeat as needed; alternatively, look at `parallel` or `xargs` for auto-magic load balancing (6 concurrent subprocesses in this case)

Comment: @markp-fuso Thanks for your input. I see where you are getting at. I will try this out. I will edit the above code to include my findings.